# How to render the partial view after getting the data from the Web Api Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to render the partial view after getting the data from the web api controller action.
I want to do the following operations:

1. Need to get the data from the web api controller using post method from jquery.
2. After getting the data from the web api, need to navigate to the main view (ex:"diplay") which is having the partial view (it is used to render the chart element).Also, passing the model data to the partial view to draw the chart using jqplot.

   Source Code:

   ## Jquery:

   ```
    $("#show").click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
          var jsondata = $("#filtercontent").text();
              var jlist;
              $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/api/CreateReports/',
                   data: "=" + jsondata,
                   success: function (json) {
                       jlst = $.toJSON(json);                                        
                   }
               });
               $.post("/reports/display", { Data: jlst },
               function (data, textStatus) {
               htmldatafordisplay = data;
               if (textStatus != "success") {
                   result = "false";
                   alert("Error");
               }
               window.location.replace("display");
               });
   ```

   ## Controller action:

   ```
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Display(string jsonData)
       {
           var mdata = new DataModel(); 
           List<DataModel> personData;
           JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           personData = jss.Deserialize<List<DataModel>>(jsonData);
           return View("display",personData);
       }
   ```

   ## Web ApiContorller action:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IEnumerable<ReportData> Post([FromBody]string value)
   {   
       var data = value.ToString();
       var model = new ReportData();
       string query = "select id, name ,value from table";
       var objdata = GetResult(query).ToList();
       return objdata;
   }
   ```

   ## Data Model:

   ```
   public class Report
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Value{ get; set; }
   }
   ```

   ## Display.cshtml:

   ```
   @model List<JobInsight.Web.Models.DataModel> 
   <div>Welcome to our sitet</div>
   <div>@{Html.RenderPartial("Chart", @Model);}</div>
   ```

   ## Chart.cshtml:

   ```
   <div id="chart" class="jqplot-target barChart">
   </div>
   <script>
           var json = Json.Encode(Model);
           var dataSlices = [];
           var ticks = [];
           $.each(json, function (entryindex, entry) {
               dataSlices.push(entry['Value']);
               ticks.push(entry['Name']);
           });


              var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart', [dataSlices], {
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barWidth: null,
                        fillToZero: true, barDirection: 'horizontal'
                    },
                    pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e' }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        pad: 0,
                        tickOptions: { formatString: "%'d" }
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ticks,
                        tickOptions: { showGridline: false },
                    }
                },
                noDataIndicator: true
                });
                </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render a completely different view then `$.post` is not going to work. You need to post your data in a `<form>` to the server and then expect a complete page

But, I don't see why you have to get the data from Web API using jQuery and then send it to server again to fetch a view. You could do all this in a single call.

Create a new Controller Action

```
public ActionResult DisplayReport(string jsonData)
{
    // call Web Api here and fetch data 
    // store the returned data in result
    return view('display', result);
}
```